# LibGDX problems with if

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, libgdx

I have this if statement in my LibGDX game. The problem is that my player watching left, he moves in the  left direction, which is correct, but if he watshes in right direction he moves left anyway. How can I solve this problem?

```
 public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.A &&  player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >=-0.5) {
            SpinDashleft();


            return true;
        }
        else   if (keycode == Input.Keys.A &&  player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <=0.5) {
            SpinDashright();


            return true;
        }


        return false;
    }
   public void SpinDashleft() {


    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-7.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);

}

public void SpinDashright() {


        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(7.00f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);

}
```

Comment: The problem is solved! It nedds to be like this
 public void SpinDash() {





      if ((player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x<=0.5 )&& !player.region.isFlipX()){
          player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.9f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
      }

      else if ((player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >=-0.5 ) && player.region.isFlipX()){
          player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.9f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);
      }



    }

Comment: You're using your texture region (an asset) to store player state? I suggest you avoid doing that--it's spaghetti code.

Comment: I'm not such good in it now and use tutorials, so that's why my code like this.

Comment: That's fine, just a suggestion. Learn the basics first, read up on good practices as you go.

Answer (score 0):

What is the 0.5 for? Check for a minimum speed? If so, you probably got the signs wrong there.

```
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.A) {
      if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= 0.5) {
        SpinDashleft();
        return true;
      }
      if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= -0.5) {
        SpinDashright();
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried to change them, but it's not solve my problem, just switch the direction in which olayer move anyway.

Comment: What happens if you just use <  and > 0?

Comment: If I use it - player is not mooving at all.